# PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown disable events of Child Controls

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.5

I am implementing a drag and drop in WPF application on ListBox

I use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown for that purpose but all the events of child controls are not working after that only PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown button event is firing every time

Comment: Post some code to answer you..

Comment: How do you know or what do you mean exactly when you say all the events of child controls are not working ?

Comment: Here I found a solution in case someone else finds this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192050/button-inside-the-datagrid-not-getting-fired-due-to-previewmouseleftbuttondown/