# Button inside the Datagrid not getting Fired due to PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application.

As per requirement I want  to show  list of item in data grid. Each row also having a “DELETE” button, using this button we can deleted the corresponding item.
I  also want Drag and Drop feature for the Grid. That is user can move the  rows  up/down.

I am using `“PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown”` and `“Drop”` event of the  datagrid to implement the Drag and Drop feature.

For DELETE button  , I have bind the Delete Command.

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=viewName,Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
```

I also tried

```
 Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
```

Now the issue is , when I click  the  “DELETE” button, the delete command handler not getting fired. But if I remove the   “PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown” and “Drop” events of the data grid , the delete command handler working perfectly.

Also I noticed that ,Even if commented all code inside the “PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown”  after add the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event, it also block the execution of  Delete command handler.

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="35"  >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="30" Content="X"     Command="{Binding ElementName=viewCSW,Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Code of PreviewMousedown

```
  private void dgEmployee_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            prevRowIndex = GetDataGridItemCurrentRowIndex(e.GetPosition);

            if (prevRowIndex < 0)
                return;
            dgEmployee.SelectedIndex = prevRowIndex;

            var selectedEmployee = dgEmployee.Items[prevRowIndex];//as Employee;

            if (selectedEmployee == null)
                return;
            //Now Create a Drag Rectangle with Mouse Drag-Effect
            //Here you can select the Effect as per your choice
            DragDropEffects dragdropeffects = DragDropEffects.Move;

            if (DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dgEmployee, selectedEmployee, dragdropeffects)
                                != DragDropEffects.None)
            {
                //Now This Item will be dropped at new location and so the new Selected Item
                dgEmployee.SelectedItem = selectedEmployee;
            }


            //      sourceElement.CaptureMouse();
            //  return;

        }
```

I am struggling with this issue.

If any one have a solution, Please let me know.

Thanks,
Ranish

Comment: Post code for Mouse down handler here. Are you setting `e.Handled=true` in that handler?

Comment: No . I am not using "e.Handled=true". Also even if I  comment the code inside the PreviewMouseDown event, the delete command not getting fired.

Comment: Add some relevant code here then to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` call to the datagrid's `MouseMove` event:

```
private void dgEmployee_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Employee selectedEmp = dgEmployee.Items[prevRowIndex] as Employee;
            if (selectedEmp == null)
                return;

            DragDropEffects dragdropeffects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            if (DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dgEmployee, selectedEmp, dragdropeffects)
                            != DragDropEffects.None)
            {
                //Now This Item will be dropped at new location and so the new Selected Item
                dgEmployee.SelectedItem = selectedEmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

The updated `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` handler:

```
void dgEmployee_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        prevRowIndex = GetDataGridItemCurrentRowIndex(e.GetPosition);

        if (prevRowIndex < 0)
            return;

        dgEmployee.SelectedIndex = prevRowIndex;
    }
```

Not only does it fix your problem but it provides a better user experience. The drag should be initiated when I move the mouse instead of when I press the row.

Next time please link the tutorial that [you are using](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=677) - it will make it much easier for others to reproduce the issue that you are encountering.

Comment: Thank you so much...!! Now it is working!! ok next time onwards I will upload sample code along with my question.