# MouseMove event prevents ComboBox being "opened"

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, mousemove

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/677/wpf-data-grid-row-drag-drop) to implement Drag&Drop on my datagrid. I changed it according to [this link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-drag-item-between-c66cc4d2) to be able to move elements between groups.

My datagrid contains a column with a button, so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196816/1117932) to make the button usable again. I also have 3 columns with ComboBoxes and they can not be used (you can click them and they then look like combo boxes but the second click does not expand it).

Two of them are defined as `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and one is defined with `DataGridTemplateColumn` and a `ComboBox` in the tag `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate`.

The first two are like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Entity" 
    ItemsSource="{StaticResource tl}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    SelectedValuePath="Name" 
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Entity}" 
    x:Name="cmbEntity"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

The definition of the DataGrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"  Name="myGrid" IsManipulationEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
RowEditEnding="myGrid_RowEditEnding" PreviewKeyDown="myGrid_PreviewKeyDown" SelectedCellsChanged="myGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
AllowDrop="True" MouseMove="DataGrid_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Drop="DataGridView_Drop">
```

And as mentioned above, the methods are implemented according to the tutorials. I have tried using `e.Handled=false` in the Event handlers, but it did not help (and it is probably useless anyway since opening the combobox is not an event?)

By removing one event handler at a time at least I found out that the MouseMove event is the problem, the code is the following:

```
    void DataGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {

            Console.Out.WriteLine("MouseButtonState.Pressed");

            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            prevRowIndex = GetDataGridItemCurrentRowIndex(dataGrid, e.GetPosition);

            if (prevRowIndex < 0) { return;}

            dataGrid.SelectedIndex = prevRowIndex;
            DefaultValue selectedDV = dataGrid.Items[prevRowIndex] as DefaultValue;

            if (selectedDV == null) { return; }

            DragDropEffects dragDropEffects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            if (DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dataGrid, selectedDV, dragDropEffects) != DragDropEffects.None)
            {
                dataGrid.SelectedItem = selectedDV;
            }    
        }
    }
```

I don't completely understand why this is happening, because I don't really  move the mouse, I just click on the cell containing the combo box. Is it somehow possible to have both, Drag&Drop and the ComboBoxes?

**EDIT:** I modified the project from [the tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/677/wpf-data-grid-row-drag-drop) I used to show the problem I have: [Download from my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ii7czsmrfq5lp4j/AACx3nomcxHY96lDPsiuE0q7a?dl=0) 
I changed the Salary column to be a combobox (and of course also added the Grouping because I think it might be important)

Comment: It would be nice, if you could post a minimalistic project showing the issue, otherwise it's time-consuming to follow through all tutorials you've done, to reproduce your error.

Comment: Ok I will do that but it will take me some time (I cannot upload the complete project because it is note my own code).

Comment: So, how is it going?

Comment: @netaholic added it right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what the problem was.

MouseMove event got fired even when mouse was clicked without moving. Quick searching suggests me that this is intendent behaviour.
Then datagrid would have tried to put clicked cell in edit mode, but mouse move event code would call `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` preventing combobox from appearing.

The workaround that I suggest would be to do the following:

Define in MainWindow:

```
        Point mousePositionOnButtonPress;
        double deltaToStartDrag = 10;
```

and modify your MouseMove event to following:

```
if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                var position = e.GetPosition(this);
                if (mousePositionOnButtonPress == new Point())
                {
                    mousePositionOnButtonPress = new Point(position.X, position.Y);
                }
                else
                    if (Math.Abs(mousePositionOnButtonPress.X - position.X) > deltaToStartDrag || Math.Abs(mousePositionOnButtonPress.Y - position.Y) > deltaToStartDrag)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("MouseButtonState.Pressed");

                        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
                        prevRowIndex = GetDataGridItemCurrentRowIndex(dataGrid, e.GetPosition);

                        if (prevRowIndex < 0) { return; }

                        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = prevRowIndex;
                        Employee selectedDV = dataGrid.Items[prevRowIndex] as Employee;

                        if (selectedDV == null) { return; }

                        DragDropEffects dragDropEffects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                        if (DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dataGrid, selectedDV, dragDropEffects) != DragDropEffects.None)
                        {
                            dataGrid.SelectedItem = selectedDV;
                        }
                    }
                //
            }
```

also subscribe to DataGrid's MouseUp event as following

```
private void dgEmployee_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            mousePositionOnButtonPress = new Point();
        }
```

This will defer start of drag and drop until user moves his mouse pressed up to 10 pixels.

This is what I have to say about your issue.
I also suggest you to take a look at this article http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop
IMO it has much more cleaner code and it looks better.
I believe that with some tweaking you can make it work with groups.

Comment: Really cool! I thought it might be something like that (MouseMove getting fired without moving), but that didn't make sense to me...